# NServiceBus custom message handler type

Tags: c#, nservicebus

Is there a way in NServiceBus to replace the IHandleMessages<> handler with my own version of this interface that isnt strongly tied to NServiceBus?

I have found ways of replacing the event/command marker interfaces (Via NServiceBus 3 Unobtrusive syntax) but no way of doing the same for the actual handler. I am trying to do this to remove the coupling between my handlers and NServiceBus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to not be possible with NServiceBus.

The way i made this as unobtrusive as possible was to create a NServiceBus proxy to forward messages to my own bus, this kept the NServiceBus references out of most of my projects.

Answer (score 2):

I found it possible with little code required:

1) Create a generic class implementing `IHandleMessages<TMessage>` and implement the Handle method making it find or create the correct instance of your custom handler (from DI container, static registry etc.). In this example assume that you've got `MyCustomHandler` class with `void HandleMessageMyWay(object message)` method accepting any message type:

```
public class MessageHandlerAdapter<TMessage>
   : IHandleMessages<TMessage>
{
    public void Handle(TMessage message)
    {
        new MyCustomHandler().HandleMessageMyWay(message);
    }
}
```

It's an open generic, so NServiceBus won't discover it as a valid handler, because you need a closed generic (with TMessage being a concrete type like MyMessage1) to be seen by NServiceBus as a handler for the concrete type.

2) Implement `ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering`.  In it's `SpecifyOrder` method make (at runtime) a closed generic adapter type for each message type which you want to support:

```
public class MessageHandlerAdapterLister : ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering
{
    public void SpecifyOrder(Order order)
    {
        //You would normally iterate through your message types (over DI registry or some other registry of messages):
        var adapterType1 = typeof(MessageHandlerAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyMessage1));
        var adapterType2 = typeof(MessageHandlerAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyMessage2));

        order.Specify(new[] { adapterType1, adapterType2 });
    }
}
```

`ISpecifyMessageHandlerOrdering` instances are automatically discovered by NServiceBus. These are normally used to specify order for handler types which are discovered by NServiceBus. Apparently when you specify types which have not been discovered (like our closed generic adapter types made at runtime), it will simply add them to the registry.

That's all you need. NServiceBus will route `MyMessage1` and `MyMessage2` through the open generic `IHandleMessages<TMessage>` which then delegates handling to your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the NServiceBus 3.0 Unobtrusive Mode (see [Andreas Ohlund's article on this](http://andreasohlund.net/2011/12/15/support-for-running-nservicebus-in-unobtrusive-mode/)) is that event definitions shared between multiple services can get into trouble if different endpoints are running different versions of NServiceBus, because the version on NServiceBus.dll that you are taking a dependency on will not match.

This argument does not hold water with the message handlers (the classes implementing IHandleMessages) themselves. There's no sharing of handlers. The message handler is, by definition, coupled to NServiceBus.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand your arguement, i suppose the reason i want this is that my application internal conecept is that i am communicating via messages. To me NServiceBus is simply the transport implementation. I would really like to be able to have a more generic concept of what a message bus is in my application context, and what a message handler looks like. I can probably do this by building a shim across the top, but if theres tooling to do this i would prefer to do it using that. Is it fair to say there isnt anything to do this in NServiceBus?